# Cache folder grown very very fast

Tags: symfony

I'm use Symfony2 into one critical application. For each client (each tab in browser is client) JS through AJAX request data each second.
And folder /cache/dev/profiler/ grown really fast! 17Gb for 2 days! How can i disable this writing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is the option in config_dev.yml

```
framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: true }
```

It was false, now all going normal.

Comment: In symfony 4 this option is at `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml`

Comment: What does changing this option actually change though?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your environment is running in dev (development) mode, if so make sure it is on prod (production).
In dev mode alot proccessing is done for debugging reasons and this is not needed for your clients.

if you wish to disable the profiler you can do it
In: `app/config/config_dev.yml`

```
web_profiler:
     toolbar: true
     only-exceptions: true
     intercept_redirects: false
```

Comment: No, that is other profiler, that stores info about every request.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/internals.html#profiler there it is descripted

Comment: I see! Just a question why would you want to run in dev env while having clients on the site?

Comment: Because it manage clients on the router and used by technical specialists while I developing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is better solution, you can store your profiler data in redis thanks to [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle), they have implemented **profiler_storage**.

They have also added TTL, so your profiler data can expire automatically.

First configure your snc_redis client in config.yml

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
```

Then add profiler storage in config_dev.yml

```
snc_redis:
    profiler_storage:
        client: default
        ttl: 86400
```

Comment: That is a really good solution for projects using Redis and SncRedisBundle!

Comment: @Najki yep, since I use the redis method I don't have problems anymore.

Answer (score 1):

my solution

```
* * * * * root cd /path/to/project/src/var/cache/dev/profiler && sed -i ':a;$q;N;101,$D;ba' ./index.csv && ls -1t | tail -n +102 | xargs rm -rf
```

where:

`sed -i ':a;$q;N;101,$D;ba' ./index.csv` removes all lines in index.csv, except last 100. (new dumps are stored last)

`ls -1t | tail -n +102 | xargs rm -rf` removes all folders and files except newest 100 by modification date.

102 - to account for index.csv